# Можно ли слать информацию апачу на уровне сокетов

Tags: c#, apache, php

Предположим есть php скрипт, который делает выборку из БД. Строка соединения выглядит примерно так :

```
$hostname = "127.0.0.1:4040";
$username = "root";
$password = "pvptime";
$dbname = "diplom"; 
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение");
```

т.е мне очень нужно с порта 4040 передать апачу логин и пароль на mysql, причём программно.
Подскажите хоть в какую сторону копать.... Заранее благодарен

Comment: Есть программы, которые так делают...Вот например http://s005.radikal.ru/i212/1403/4a/c9b4c5cc7a66.png

Comment: такое ощущение, что середина вопроса где то уплыла.

Comment: Апач и так работает с информацией на уровне сокетов. Вы, кажется, теряетесь в терминологии.